# Необходимо вывести 111, а программа выводит ['1', '1', '1']

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f = [1,1,1]
print(f)
```

Очень важная универсальность программы, так как f = [1,1,1] не всегда принимает это значение.

Comment: А какое значение принимает ещё?

Comment: Любую последовательность целых чисел

Answer (score 6):

Используйте [str.join](https://pythonz.net/references/named/str.join/):

```py
f = [1,1,1]
print(''.join([str(i) for i in f]))
```

Comment: Или `map(str, f)` вместо comprehension

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идет только о **выводе**, уместно вспомнить функцию ***print()***:

Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

```
print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
    
    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
    flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```

Итого, вся программа такая:

```
f = [1,1,1]
print(*f, sep="")
```

Работает!

Answer (score 0):

```
f = [1,1,1]
a=''
for i in f:
    a+=str(i)
print(a)
```